# What's the correct way to work with CLion remote development

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm  trying to understand how to work with CLion remote development. What I'm trying to do is to have a Docker image with the toolchains and all the dependencies needed to build the application, and have all the developers using the same docker image during development, so when there's a change in the build environment the update is made to the Docker image, and all the developers are immediately up to date after only `docker pull`.

So basically the flow I'm interested in is that after build, the artifact may be available on the developer's machine so it can do whatever with it.
I followed [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html) in order to achieve this. The steps are in general:

1. Create a `Remote` toolchain in **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains** configured with the details of the docker container containing all the tools.
2. Create a CMake Profile in **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake** that uses the above toolchain.

But there are some things I don't understand

1. "Exclude paths" - There's a tab of "Exclude paths" to each Deployment entry. When I create the Docker Toolchain, CLion creates an entry in the `Deployment`s list which corresponds to the Docker container remote host. The thing is, it automatically adds the `cmake-build-docker` directory to the `Exclude paths` which I can't understand why??!!
2. How can I extract the binary from within the container after the build?

Comment: Here is a good article how to use Docker with CLion https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/01/using-docker-with-clion/

Comment: >How can I extract the binary from within the container after the build?

There is a registry key `clion.remote.sync.text.files` which let you transfer all binary files back to host machine. To open registry option dialog call *Help | Find Action | Registry ...*